# Passing array of data in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony-3.4

I have my notification table in db where I am setting all read notifications by user.

For now, this function receives only one id, but also, there should be an option to pass array of ids there, to mark several at once as read. I need to extend this function so that it handles the case where $this>data['id'] is array.

How can I fix it?

My code:

```
public function readNotification(User $user, $notificationId)      
{                                                                  

   $notification = $this->getNotificationRepository()->findOneBy([
       'user' => $user,                                           
       'id' => $notificationId                                    
   ]);  

   if($notification) {                                            
       $notification->setRead(new \DateTime());                   
       $this->em->flush();                                        
   }                                                              
}
```

My controller:

```
$this->requirePostParams(['id']);
    $this->get('app.service')->readNotification(
        $this->data['user'],
        $this->data['id']
    );

    return $this->success();
```

Comment: Check if provided `$notificationId` is array or not.

Comment: It's not! I thought   $notificationId = []; would do the trick. No? @u_mulder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real life it is a very bad approach to get all notifications and save each notification with `flush`. Suppose with your case you should update 1K or more notifications. This will cause 1K update queries. I advise you to create a distinct `UPDATE` query and update all related items in a single query:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `read` = NOW() WHERE id IN (id1, id2, ....)
```

`id1, id2 ...` is a list of ids that you want to update.

In your function you can do something like:

```
public function readNotification(User $user, $notificationIds)
{
    if (!is_array($notificationIds)) {
        $notificationIds = [$notificationIds];
    }

    // other code

}
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks a lot! @u_mulder